# How to get JSON from "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json? " to array in swift

Tags: json, swift, google-maps

I'm trying to get JSON from "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json? " to (swift 3) tableView Controller with array .
but the data that return from google api is dictionary and error to put on tableView  what should i do with my code ?

Any answer will be helpful

this is my code:

```
    var listData : [[String : AnyObject]] = [[String : AnyObject]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self

    let myURL : URL = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=13.88068,100.43575&radius=300&type=gas_station&key=YOURKEY")!

    Alamofire.request(myURL).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in
        switch response.result{
        case .success:

            self.listData = response.result.value as! [[String : AnyObject]]

            print(self.listData.description)

            self.tableView.reloadData()

            case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }

    })
```

Comment: Learn how to parse, understand JSON structure. `let json = response.result.value as [String:Any]; self.listData = json["result"] as [[String:Any]]` (but doing `if let` and other check need to be done too).

Comment: What data do you need from this JSON?

Comment: @a.afanasiev 

I want to get the list of google place data with place name + description from google web service and put it on to the tableView .
I'm try to used the google nearby place API but it's can't filter "type" and radius.

Answer (score 2):

You are casting the result to an array (an array of dictionaries, more accurately). But the response is not an array. It is a dictionary. But the value associated with its `results` key *is* an array of dictionaries:

```
var listData = [[String: Any]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self

    let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=13.88068,100.43575&radius=300&type=gas_station&key=YOURKEY")!

    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            guard let json = value as? [String: Any], let listData = json["results"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
                print("Response does not contain results")
                return
            }

            self.listData = listData

            print(listData)

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```